# No import option found on Welcome screen of intellij 2021.2-community

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I was trying to import an existing maven project from one drive directory to another. But I did not find any import option on my recently updated intelliJ idea's community version 2021.2.
Can someone please help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Import and Open actions were combined to the one Open action. If you point IDE to the existing project, it will automatically open it, if you point to the directory without project files, it will import it.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder, sounds interesting, just tried it but it seems like a new project only.. not sure on- From which source folder it will import the project? and which type of project (i.e. Mvn or gradle ) it will be?